# Parallel.ForEach() vs. foreach(IEnumerable<T>.AsParallel())

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, plinq

Erg, I'm trying to find these two methods in the BCL using Reflector, but can't locate them. What's the difference between these two snippets?

A:

```
IEnumerable<string> items = ...

Parallel.ForEach(items, item => {
   ...
});
```

B:

```
IEnumerable<string> items = ...

foreach (var item in items.AsParallel())
{
   ...
}
```

Are there different consequences of using one over the other? (Assume that whatever I'm doing in the bracketed bodies of both examples is thread safe.)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

They do something quite different.

The first one takes the anonymous delegate, and runs multiple threads on this code in parallel for all the different items.

The second one not very useful in this scenario. In a nutshell it is intended to do a query on multiple threads, and combine the result, and give it again to the calling thread. So the code on the foreach statement stays always on the UI thread.

It only makes sense if you do something expensive in the linq query to the right of the `AsParallel()` call, like:

```
 var fibonacciNumbers = numbers.AsParallel().Select(n => ComputeFibonacci(n));
```

Comment: What's the benefit over simply doing a parallel foreach on the computefibonacci?

Answer (score 59):

The second method will not be parallel the correct way to use AsParallel() in your example would be

```
IEnumerable<string> items = ...

items.AsParallel().ForAll(item =>
{
    //Do parallel stuff here
});
```

Comment: Why use the combination of asparallel along with forall instead of simply foreach?

Comment: Simply foreach wouldn't run parallel.

Answer (score 55):

The difference is, B isn't parallel. The only thing `AsParallel()` does is that it wraps around a `IEnumerable`, so that when you use LINQ methods, their parallel variants are used. The wrapper's `GetEnumerator()` (which is used behind the scenes in the `foreach`) even returns the result of the original collection's `GetEnumerator()`.

BTW, if you want to look at the methods in Reflector, `AsParallel()` is in the  `System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable` class in the `System.Core` assembly. `Parallel.ForEach()` is in the `mscorlib` assembly (namespace `System.Threading.Tasks`).

Comment: What do you mean by ... Their parallel variants are used...?

Comment: @punctuation That, for example, when you write `.Select()`, it calls `ParallelEnumerable.Select()` and not the normal `Enumerable.Select()`.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between these two snippets?

The first snippet is parallel and the second is not.

1. The first snippet invokes the `...` code on parallel on multiple [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) threads, including also the current thread as one of the worker threads.
2. The second snippet invokes the `...` code sequentially on the current thread only.

Enumerating the `items.AsParallel()` is practically the same as simply enumerating the `items`. Attaching the `AsParallel` PLINQ operator this way only serves at creating confusion to anyone reading the code. The `AsParallel` is intended as a starting point for attaching more PLINQ operators to the query. As a standalone operator it does nothing.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq#the-parallelenumerable-class):

| ParallelEnumerable Operator | Description |
| --- | --- |
| [AsParallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel) | The entry point for PLINQ. Specifies that the rest of the query should be parallelized, if it is possible. |