# How can I convert this foreach code to Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, parallel.foreach

I am a bit of confused about `Parallel.ForEach`.
What is `Parallel.ForEach` and what does it exactly do?
Please don't reference any MSDN link.

Here's a simple example :

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtProxyListPath.Text);
List<string> list_lines = new List<string>(lines);

foreach (string line in list_lines)
{
    //My Stuff
}
```

How can I rewrite this example with `Parallel.ForEach`?

Comment: This might have been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789998/parallel-foreach-vs-foreachienumerablet-asparallel

Comment: @UjjwalManandhar That's actually quite different, as it's asking about the difference between the `Parallel` class and using PLINQ.

Comment: Others have answered how you can rewrite. So what does it do? It does an "action" on each item in the collection, just like a normal `foreach`. The difference is that the parallel version can do many "actions" at the same time. In most cases (depending on what computer is running the code, and how busy it is, and other stuff) it will be faster, and that's the most important advantage. Note that when you do it in parallel, you can not know in what *order* the items are processed. With a usual (serial) `foreach`, you are guaranteed that `lines[0]` comes first, then `lines[1]`, and so on.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It will *not* always be faster as there is significant overhead with making things parallel.  It depends on the size of the collection you are iterating on and the action within.  The correct thing to do is to actually *measure* the difference between using Parallel.ForEach() and using foreach().  Many times a normal foreach() is faster.

Comment: @DaveBlack Sure. One will have to _measure_ whether it is faster or slower, in each case. I was just trying to describe parallelization in general.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtProxyListPath.Text);
List<string> list_lines = new List<string>(lines);
Parallel.ForEach(list_lines, line =>
{
    //Your stuff
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to point it out (more for the OP) so that there wasn't a misguided thought that it only works on `List<T>` ;)

Comment: thanks for the attention and answer. i used List<string> in my codes because of removing duplicate items using HASH lists. with regular array we can not remove duplicates easily:).

Comment: I am confused that this answer is marked as the right answer, since there is no explanation to the original posts question "What is Parallel.ForEach and what does it exactly do?"...

Comment: @fosb The problem is the question title was edited to completely change the meaning... so this answer no longer makes any sense. Having said that, it's still a poor answer

Answer (score 318):

**Foreach loop:**

> - Iterations takes place sequentially, one by one
> - foreach loop is run from a single Thread.
> - foreach loop is defined in every framework of .NET
> - Execution of *slow* processes can be *slower*, as they're run serially
>
>   - Process 2 can't start until 1 is done. Process 3 can't start until 2 & 1 are done...
> - Execution of *quick* processes can be *faster*, as there is no threading overhead

**Parallel.ForEach:**

> - Execution takes place in parallel way.
> - Parallel.ForEach uses multiple Threads.
> - Parallel.ForEach is defined in .Net 4.0 and above frameworks.
> - Execution of *slow* processes can be *faster*, as they can be run in parallel
>
>   - Processes 1, 2, & 3 *may* run concurrently (see reused threads in example, below)
> - Execution of *quick* processes can be *slower*, because of additional threading overhead

The following example clearly demonstrates the difference between traditional foreach loop and

**Parallel.ForEach() Example**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ParallelForEachExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] colors = {
                                  "1. Red",
                                  "2. Green",
                                  "3. Blue",
                                  "4. Yellow",
                                  "5. White",
                                  "6. Black",
                                  "7. Violet",
                                  "8. Brown",
                                  "9. Orange",
                                  "10. Pink"
                              };
            Console.WriteLine("Traditional foreach loop\n");
            //start the stopwatch for "for" loop
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            foreach (string color in colors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, Thread Id= {1}", color, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("foreach loop execution time = {0} seconds\n", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            Console.WriteLine("Using Parallel.ForEach");
            //start the stopwatch for "Parallel.ForEach"
             sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Parallel.ForEach(colors, color =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, Thread Id= {1}", color, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            );
            Console.WriteLine("Parallel.ForEach() execution time = {0} seconds", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Traditional foreach loop
1. Red, Thread Id= 10
2. Green, Thread Id= 10
3. Blue, Thread Id= 10
4. Yellow, Thread Id= 10
5. White, Thread Id= 10
6. Black, Thread Id= 10
7. Violet, Thread Id= 10
8. Brown, Thread Id= 10
9. Orange, Thread Id= 10
10. Pink, Thread Id= 10
foreach loop execution time = 0.1054376 seconds
```

**Using Parallel.ForEach example**

```
1. Red, Thread Id= 10
3. Blue, Thread Id= 11
4. Yellow, Thread Id= 11
2. Green, Thread Id= 10
5. White, Thread Id= 12
7. Violet, Thread Id= 14
9. Orange, Thread Id= 13
6. Black, Thread Id= 11
8. Brown, Thread Id= 10
10. Pink, Thread Id= 12
Parallel.ForEach() execution time = 0.055976 seconds
```

Comment: Well, the parallel for each means that separate threads are set up to execute the code in the loop body. Even though .NET does have efficient mechanism to do this, this is considerable overhead. So, if you just have to a simple operation (e.g. a sum or multiplication), the parallel foreach should not be faster.

Comment: @Jignesh this is not even good measurement example so I would not refer to this at all. Remove "Thread.Sleep(10);" from each loop body and try it again.

Comment: @Martao is right, problem is with object locking overheads where parallel approach might be longer than sequential.

Comment: @stenly I think the Sleep is precisely the reason why it is a _good_ example. You would not use a PFE with fast single iterations (as Martao explained) - so this answer is making the iteration slow, and the (correct) advantage of PFE is highlighted. I agree though that this needs to be explained in the answer, a bold "is always faster" is very misleading.

Comment: @Highmastdon - take a read at when Parallel can be slower. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/06/9703059.aspx

Comment: But he stated in his answer "Execution is faster (if single iterations are slow)". It has to be measured in edge cases, where the operation inside the loop is not that slow.

Comment: See [MSDN's *Do Not Assume That Parallel Is Always Faster*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism#do-not-assume-that-parallel-is-always-faster) and [*Avoid Over-Parallelization*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-in-data-and-task-parallelism#avoid-over-parallelization): "*The basic rule [is] parallel loops that have few iterations and fast user delegates are unlikely to speedup much.*" Also limited by # of proc cores & "costs of partitioning & synchronizing"

Comment: @stenly, The Sleep(10) represents an API call that you may need to make for each line.

Comment: Also depends on the number of cores in the processor. The more cores available, the more speedy the loop would be. By default, all the cores would be used by parallel, so the number of cores participating should be specified at the parallel call code.

Answer (score 47):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtProxyListPath.Text);

// No need for the list
// List<string> list_lines = new List<string>(lines); 

Parallel.ForEach(lines, line =>
{
    //My Stuff
});
```

This will cause the lines to be parsed in parallel, within the loop.  If you want a more detailed, less "reference oriented" introduction to the Parallel class, I wrote a series on the TPL which includes a [section on Parallel.ForEach](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/20/parallelism-in-net-part-2-simple-imperative-data-parallelism/).

Answer (score 11):

For big file use the following code (you are less memory hungry)

```
Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(txtProxyListPath.Text), line => {
    //Your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 6):

These lines Worked for me.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtProxyListPath.Text);
var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 10 };
Parallel.ForEach(lines , options, (item) =>
{
 //My Stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add about parallel options. If you don't mentioned it, by default all RAM will be utilize for this which may give you problem in production. So better to add max degree of parallelism too in code.

```cs
Parallel.ForEach(list_lines, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, line =>
{
    
});
```