# does parallel foreach creates different copies of functions in it

Tags: c#

I have following scenario ,

```
Parallel.Foreach(al , sentence =>
{
  function abc
   {
      double x;
   }
   y = Add(ref y, x)
}

 public static double Add(ref double location1, double value)
        {
            double newCurrentValue = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                double currentValue = newCurrentValue;
                double newValue = currentValue + value;
                newCurrentValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref location1, newValue, currentValue);
                if (newCurrentValue == currentValue)
                    return newValue;
            }
        }
```

for each sentence in array of sentence al there is some value of x that will be calculated. And I want to sum up these values of all sentences in to variable y. But when I run code each time I get different value of y. And I guess its because x is getting overwritten before writing into y. So for each sentence is Parallel Foreach creating different or same copy of function abc? How can I fix this.

Comment: This is not valid C# syntax

Comment: How about posting a real compilable code?

Comment: And I'm more bothered about logic than syntax. The codes is too big.

Comment: You're being down voted by people that don't understand...the code is accurate they've just never seen it.

Try taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251874/how-use-parallel-foreach-loop-instead-of-regular-foreach-info-about-parallel-f

Comment: "How about posting a real compilable code?" does not mean "How about posting your entire application?". See [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JoeSwindell the code originally posted did make no sense

Answer (score 2):

Since multiple threads access to `y` for writing at the same time

For ex, below code may not result in 4950

```
int y=0;
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 100), x => y += x);
```

but this one ensures it

```
 int z = 0;
 Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 100), x => Interlocked.Add(ref z, x));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `y= y+x;` is not thread-safe. Use [`Interlocked.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33821kfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead

```
Interlocked.Add(ref y, x);
```

Comment: I tried that now, see edited code, still same. I think value of x is getting overwritten before it writes to y.

Comment: @user3667737 The code you posted is not what I suggested, and is not thread-safe at all. Replace this line `y = Add(ref y, x)` with what I posted, and delete your `Add` method.

Comment: @user3667737 Oh yeah, you're right. Ok, then change your `Add` method to return `void`, and call it like this `Add(ref y, x)`, instead of this `y = Add(ref y, x)`. That should make the operation atomic.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, summing/assigning by itself isn't thread safe. However `Interlocked.Add` can't be used for doubles. That would leave the option for locking, however, there is an easier way, using your pseudo code:

```
var y= al.AsParallel().Select(sentence => function(sentence )).Sum();
```

This uses the `double Sum(this ParallelQuery<double> source)` which is thread safe

*edit* 
In the updated code you've posted, y is still assigned inside multiple threads (`y = Add(ref y, x)` ), which is't thread safe. Instead of the add function you could use the suggestion above.