# using a c# foreach on List<T> to check for default date values

Tags: c#, aspose-cells

I initially wanted to quickly select certain records (using a `Linq` qry) which match a default date condition (`01/01/0001`) -

```
var defDates = (from rec in myRecords where rec.myDate == System.DateTime.MinValue select rec.myDate);
```

and then update those record(s) to a `Null` value. However, since those returned records have only a `get`, it means they are read-only (makes sense since I'm using Linq).

So the best I could come up with is a c# `foreach` which will catch default dates and sets to Null (i.e. I'm exporting to `Excel` via `Aspose.cells`, so I need those cell values to just be blank):

```
foreach (myExportClass rec in myRecords)
{
    if (rec.myDate == System.DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        rec.myDate = null;
    }
};
```

Okay, this works, and exports the required Null value(s) to Excel (a blank cell, actually).

However, the question is: could I find a more efficient way of handling this default date scenario ? Seems to me that a foreach() may waste resources if there are several thousand records coming back.

Fyi: the records are coming back from the backend this way, so I need to deal with this in c#.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you having an actual problem with runtime performance? At any rate, I don't think there's a special high-speed looping construct in .NET.

Comment: What resources are you expecting a `foreach` to consume that aren't actually needed for your situation?

Comment: Might want to look into `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: Two questions about the `foreach` you propose: 1) where is `myObj` comming from? is the looping variable? in that case you should rename it to `rec` or viceversa. 2) you break (i.e. exit the loop) after the first default date is found, is that correct? That way you only "fix" the first one...

Comment: Why the `break;`? it means you only change the first value you find to null... I don't think you can get much more efficient then this, but you can use the `ForEach` extension method on your `List<T>` with a lambda to make it shorter: `myRecords.ForEach(r => {if(r.MyDate == DateTime.MinValue) r.MyDate = null;});`

Comment: @BurnsBA Unless `myDate` is some expensive to compute property getter, that'd almost certainly be slower.

Comment: @ZoharPeled What problems are you solving by doing that?  The code isn't even any shorter than the code in the question, nor does it perform better.

Comment: @servy I don't follow. Enumerate several thousand records sequentially and check & update them one at a time, or enumerate them in parallel and check & update them that way.

Comment: i'd use default(DateTime) instead of DateTime.MinValue

Comment: @Servy It's not solving any problem. As I wrote it's not going to be more efficient, just a bit shorter - a single line instead of 3 (not counting the `{` and `}`. That's why it's a comment and not an attempted answer.

Comment: @BurnsBA - because creating and destroying threads is not free (to the CPU / application).  If the operation is simple enough that it can be accomplished faster than the time it takes to create threads, you can actually see a performance **decrease** using `Parallel.ForEach` due to the added overhead of thread management. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17486002/130387

Comment: @BurnsBA The overhead you have from managing the threads is going to be *significantly* more expensive than the single date equality comparison (and infrequently, also an assignment).  And the enumeration of the sequence is going to be done serially in either case (as the underlying collection can only be accessed from a single thread safely).  Unless the actual work being done concurrently is expensive (which isn't the case here unless `myDate` is some expensive property getter) that will take more time, not less.

Comment: @ZoharPeled If you want to remove the line breaks, then you can just remove the line breaks.  You don't need to call another method that doesn't do anything productive in order to remove some unnecessary whitespace from your code.

Comment: Just leave your foreach as is. Looping over several thousands items costs nothing compared to reading them from your backend, and you don't need any improvement in that part (and your linq query above performs the same foreach). If you ever find problems with performance - I bet they will not be here.

Comment: To all, I changed myObj to rec within the foreach (). I only used the break for one test case, however I removed it since I need to check all records.

Comment: What is the size of the collection, do have any approximate values ?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments guys. The lead dev on my team does code reviews, and is very critical - so I wanted to be a step ahead by attempting to write the best code. I.e. I was concerned that I would loop thousands of records unnecessarily if there was a quicker way.

Comment: Keep in mind that even iterating a million sized collection in relatively old processor will take no more then 5 - 15 ms. This are really rough number ... everything is relative of of course (cpu, ram  .. etc), but just keep in mind that iterating si not slow at all.

Comment: @vasil, it appears not very large. I only see a couple hundred recs at the most.  I do need to confirm the max collection size with the DB folks, however.

Comment: Have you tried using PLinq?

collection.Where(test => test.Time <= DateTime.MinValue).AsParallel().ForAll(test => test.Time = null)

Comment: If it is couple of hundred recs, don't worry about it. You've done it the right way ;)

Comment: couldn't you just use a `select new myExportClass { myDate = null};` in the linq query and avoid the need to loop over the list?

Comment: @FerdinandBrunauer That's going to be noticeably slower than a regular foreach, for reason already mentioned in earlier comments.

Comment: @Sorceri That is a different behavior; it's not a functionally equivalent translation.  Additionally, constructing a new value for each item is *going* to be more expensive than the assignment.  And you're iterating over the collection in either case, whether you iterate over it to create a new value or to mutate the existing value doesn't change that you're iterating over it.