# Multi-threading in Enumerator

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am using C# and I have an enumerator and I am reading the data inside the enumerator sequentially.

This is a third party library object and does not support Parallel.Foreach

```
while(enumerator.Next())
{
  var item = enumerator.Read();
  ProcessItem(item);
}

ProcessItem(Item item)
{
// Is lock required here
 if(item.prop == "somevalue")
   this._list.Add(item);
}
```

I want to achieve multithreading here while reading the content.

```
while(enumerator.Next())
{
  // This code should run in a multi-threaded way

  var item = enumerator.Read();
  // ProcessItem method puts these items on a class level list property 
  // Is there any Lock required?
  ProcessItem(item);
}
```

I am new to multithreading. Please share any code samples which satisfies the above requirement.

Comment: refer this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56575/Thread-safe-enumeration-in-C

Comment: do you mean `ProcessItem(item)` does something like `_list.Add(item)`? depending on the `_list` type it requires locking.
if you expand some details it will help (show the code for ProcessItem)

Comment: Yes, based on some condition, it adds some of the items in the list. For eg: If(item.prop == "something") then _list.Add(item);

Comment: The example from codeproject is probably not what you need. I would not recommend to use it, not only because it breach the Gendarme `DoNotUseLockedRegionOutsideMethodRule` rule *(and not only this rule)*. As far as I understand this, I would use custom implementation of `IEnumerator` with lock for getting the objects. But it depends also on real implementation of `ProcessItems`, like stated by Ashkan Nourzadeh. With the request to change the list within it's enumeration the code can be really complex and I would say, you should search another way, without the change of list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use a Parallel.ForEach loop instead of a regular foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251874/when-to-use-a-parallel-foreach-loop-instead-of-a-regular-foreach)

Comment: I wonder if .NET built-in functions for parallel loops don't fit your needs. Check Parallel.ForEach (shipped in .NET 4.0)

Comment: This is a third party object and does not support Parallel.Foreach

Comment: Somebody downvoted the question by giving some links reference but does not satisfy the requirement

Comment: @AnkurArora check the edited [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578839/2669438)

Comment: What do you mean by `does not support Parallel.ForEach`? `Parallel.ForEach` can accept *any* `IEnumerable`. This object does not have to be thread-safe and most of the time it is not.

Comment: As it is a third party library, I could see just metadata and noticed that they haven't implemented the IEnumerable interface. I liked the idea of wrapping that in our custom enumerator and then using TPL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, some locking required. you can achieve it using lock or using a concurrent collection type.

using `lock`:

```
ProcessItem(Item item)
{
    if(item.prop == "somevalue")
    {
        lock(_list)
        {
            _list.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: based on detail you provided, you can wrap the `enumerator` from external lib using your own enumerator like below so you can use `Parallel.ForEach` on it:

We assume the enumerator you got is something like `MockEnumerator`, we wrap it in a normal IEnumerator, and IEnumerable so we are able to use `Parallel.ForEach` to read in parallel.

```
class Program
{
    class Item
    {
        public int SomeProperty { get; }

        public Item(int prop)
        {
            SomeProperty = prop;
        }
    }

    class MockEnumerator
    {
        private Item[] _items = new Item[] { new Item(1), new Item(2) };
        private int _position = 0;

        public bool Next()
        {
            return _position++ < _items.Length;
        }

        public Item Read()
        {
            return _items[_position];
        }
    }

    class EnumeratorWrapper : IEnumerator<Item>, IEnumerable<Item>
    {
        private readonly MockEnumerator _enumerator;

        public EnumeratorWrapper(MockEnumerator enumerator)
        {
            this._enumerator = enumerator;
        }

        public Item Current => _enumerator.Read();

        object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return _enumerator.Next();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this;
        }
    }

    private static List<Item> _list = new List<Item>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var enumerator = new EnumeratorWrapper(new MockEnumerator());
        Parallel.ForEach(enumerator, item =>
        {
            if (item.SomeProperty == 1)//someval
            {
                lock (_list)
                {
                    _list.Add(item);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example for task-based parallelization. Each processing of an item corresponds to a task. Hence, you can change the loop to the following:

```
  var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
  while(enumerator.MoveNext())
  {
    var item = enumerator.Current;

    Task<int> task = new Task<int>(() => ProcessItem(item));
    task.Start();
    tasks.Add(task);
  }


  foreach(Task<int> task in tasks)
  {
    int i = task.Result;
    classList.Add(i);
  }
```

Note that the synchronization on the `classList` is implicitly given by first spawning *all* tasks in the while loop and then merging the results in the foreach loop. The synchronization is specifically given by the access to `Result` which [waits until the corresponding task is finished](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx).