# c# Parallel.Invoke vs Parallel.ForEach - process data source and modify it in parallel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, parallel.invoke

Can somebody explain what path to use `Paralle.Invoke` or `Parallel.ForEach` in this scenario:

```
- query large data from database let's say 1000 records
- parallel process this data, save the records back to db, eventually insert new records etc
```

So the data will be returned like a List and then I have specific methods that will process certain records from the list based on a category property.

What should I use: .ForEach or .Invoke?

Comment: It refers to processing, so.. what sort of processing do you have to do.

Comment: Depends on what kind of `processing` you want to perform. Write the processing code in a standard `foreach`/`for` loop and compare that with `Parallel.ForEach`, see which one is faster. Also be careful with concurrent inserts and make sure the records are not coupled in any way.

Comment: Basically, for each record there will be some calculation done, some service calls, update that specific record and insert some new record in a completely different table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use a Parallel.ForEach loop instead of a regular foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12251874/1260204) (*see answer with the most number of votes*)

Comment: @Igor: What about Parallel.Invoke ?

Comment: You can process the data using whichever `Parallel` you like, but you must save it using the same thread that fetched it from EF. Your context isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score -2):

Several different tasks that have nothing to do with each other?

```
Parallel.Invoke
```

Several sequential tasks that need each others result?

```
Parallel.ForEach
```