# Use multiple threads to deal with rows in DataTable?

Tags: multithreading

```
//get rows from db

foreach(DataRow r in rows)
{
//connect to some other database
//update some record in datatable
//insert record into datatable
//etc...
//...
}
```

How to use **multiple threads** mechanism to rewrite the above code, then we can get benefit from **multiple servers**?

Answer (score 4):

**maybe this will help**

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> items = ...

Parallel.ForEach(items, item => {
   ...
});
```

[Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789998/parallel-foreach-vs-foreachienumerablet-asparallel)